# Как рекурсивной функции вычислить сумму номеров цифр?

Tags: kotlin, рекурсия

Дано число, внутри рекурсивной функции нужно вычислить сумму номеров цифр. Наприме 452-> 1+2+3 или 65984->1+2+3+4+5. В коде ниже нашёл количество цифр в числе но никак не могу найти сумму номеров цифр.

[image: Смог найти количество цифр но не могу найти сумму номеров цифр]

Comment: "Сумма номеров" считается элементарной формулой для суммы арифметической прогрессии. А если не знаешь формулы, то можно догадаться сделать банальный цикл и складывать числа от 1 до a

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000003C-QINU%60%22'%7F_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивную функцию написать не так уже элементарно, если не применять формулу к количеству цифр (что рекурсией как раз посчитать легко) -  я так понимаю, что фраза `внутри рекурсивной функции` требует, чтобы эта самая функция возвращала сразу нужный результат.

Рекурсия здесь требует знания, какая по очереди цифра обрабатывается - это параметр `d`. На Python (`//` - целочисленное деление):

```
def num(n, d = 1):
    if n > 9:
        return d + num(n // 10, d + 1)
    else:
        return d
```